# Travis could not find source file

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

For a php library, I'm using travis-ci.org. My `.travis.yml` file is as follow:

```
language: php
sudo: false
matrix:
    include:
        - php: 5.3.3
        - php: 5.3
        - php: 5.3
          env: deps=low
        - php: 5.4
        - php: 5.5
        - php: 5.6
        - php: 7
        - php: hhvm
    fast_finish: true
before_script:
    - cp phpunit.xml.dist phpunit.xml
    - composer update
    - mkdir -p log/codeCoverage
script: phpunit
```

My PHP Unit is failing on travis server (Passing locally) with following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Phpreboot\Stopwatch\StopWatch' not found in /home/travis/build/phpreboot/stopwatch/tests/Phpreboot/Stopwatch/StopWatchTest.php on line 31
```

**Question: Can someone please tell why it is failing only on travis?**

**Source - [StopWatchTest.php](https://github.com/phpreboot/stopwatch/blob/master/tests/Phpreboot/Stopwatch/StopWatchTest.php)**

```
//line 14
use Phpreboot\Stopwatch\StopWatch;

//line 29-32
public function setUp()
{
    $this->stopWatch = new StopWatch(); //Error showing here.
    // Using PSR-4 as shown in below composer.json.
}
```

**Source [composer.json](https://github.com/phpreboot/stopwatch/blob/master/composer.json)**

```
{
  "name": "phpreboot/stopwatch",
  "description": "PHP utility library for Stopwatch. Useful for optimization and other purpose.",
  "keywords": ["stopwatch", "timer"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "kapilsharma",
      "email": "***********",
      "homepage": "http://blog.kapilsharma.info",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/phpreboot/stopwatch/issues"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Phpreboot\\": "src/PhpReboot"}
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {"Phpreboot\\": "tests/PhpReboot"}
  },
  "require": {},
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8"
  }
}
```

Test result - https://travis-ci.org/phpreboot/stopwatch/jobs/82350524 (Check line 226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your autoload is wrong. See `src/PhpReboot` and that of the name of directory. It should be `src/Phpreboot` More over it is not a travis issue.

Comment: Thanks @Hari K T . My Bad, I wonder why it was working locally which make me feel my everything was right. :(

Comment: It was working locally because you were probably working on an operating system with a case-insensitive file system, such as OS X.